# Sequence of terms in a series is unbounded out side its region of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ be a series with radius of convergence $R$, then show that the sequence $\{a_nz_0^n\}$ is unbounded for $|z_0|>R$.

My thought: Can we take $|a_n|^\frac{1}{n}\geq \frac{1}{R} $ from Cauchy Hadamard formula? Any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply this: We know that $R = \lim \inf \frac 1 {|a_n|^{1/n}}$. So for $|z_0| > R$, we have $\frac {z_0} R = \lim \sup |a_n z_0^n|^{1/n} > 1$. So there exists some $r>1$ such that there are infinitely many terms of $|a_n z_0^n|^{1/n} > r$. In other words, for infinitely many $n$, we get that $|a_n z_0^n|> r^n$

Comment: You have typed $r_n$ for $r^{n}$.

Comment: Fixed, thank you